# CTE - cannot query the results twice

Tags: sql, common-table-expression

Here is a very simple CTE:

```
;
WITH test
AS
(
       SELECT GETDATE() AS CurrentDate
)

SELECT * FROM test

SELECT * FROM test
```

Why can't I select twice on the CTE table? The second select statement returns an error:

> *(1 row(s) affected)
>
> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
>
> Invalid object name 'test'.*

Comment: Because that's how CTEs are designed

Comment: A CTE is essentially a temporary view, it exists in memory (rather than physically existing) for the duration of the single query and after that is removed.

For more info see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10196808/use-one-cte-many-times

Comment: From [the documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - *A common table expression (CTE) can be thought of as a temporary result set that is defined within the execution scope of a single SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or CREATE VIEW statement. A CTE is similar to a derived table in that it is not stored as an object and lasts only for the duration of the query. Unlike a derived table, a CTE can be self-referencing and can be referenced multiple times in the same query.*