# Delete and Left Join CTE many times

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, google-bigquery

I need to use CTE many times in my stored procedure, one for delete and three for left join, I marked below. I read that I am not supposed to query CTE more than one time. Could anyone please suggest me how to rewrite the code? Thanks

My SP code:

```
WITH T1 AS   
(
  SELECT ID, Event, SN, Note
FROM je
WHERE je.Event in ('1601','1602') 
AND DATE(Time) = DATE_ADD(current_date(), INTERVAL -1 DAY)
) 
, T2 AS 
(
    SELECT SELECT ID, Event, SN, Note
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, case when Note like '%@%' and Event='1602' then 'Y' else 'N' end ORDER BY SN DESC) AS Sort
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, case when Note like '%@%' then 'Y' else 'N' end ORDER BY SN DESC) AS SortI1
    FROM T1
)
DELETE * FROM A Where ID in (SELECT ID from T2)  --#1

INSERT INTO A(
.
.
)
SELECT 
.
.
FROM G
Left Join (SELECT DISTINCT ID, Event FROM T2) k1 --#2
on G.ID=k1.ID
Left Join (SELECT ID, Event, Note like '%@%' FROM T2 where Event='1602') k2 --#3
on G.ID=k2.ID
Left Join (SELECT ID, Event, Note not like '%@%' FROM T2 where Event in ('1601','1602')) k3 --#4
on G.ID=k3.ID
WHERE k1.Event in ('1601','1602')
;
```

Comment: *"I read that I am not supposed to query CTE more than one time."* I don't think what you are saying here, and what you mean are the same. There's nothing wrong with referencing a CTE more than once, but that *isn't* what you are trying to do here. A CTE is an *expression* and it can only be referenced in the statement you *define* it in. Your `INSERT` statement is an entirely seperate statement (if you terminated your statements, which you really should, you would see this). You need to define the CTE at the start of the statement; you can't reuse it in a later statement as it doesn't exist.

Comment: Though that query you've given us it's valid T-SQL. `DATE_ADD`, `CURRENT_DATE`, `DATE` aren't T-SQL functions, and `INTERVAL` isn't a T-SQL keyword. Are you *sure* you're using SQL Server?

Comment: is this [tag:postgresql]? furthermore i don't see anything resembling stored procedure declaration.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/10196857/13097065, I think it contains the cue you are looking for

Comment: @ThomA Do you mean that I should write another CTE before Insert?

Comment: That would be one solution, @Ching . Though, maybe, BigQuery works differently; I know nothing about it and your incorrect tag was what brought me here.

Comment: @ThomA However, the table je is really big, that's why I want to use one CTE to extract the data I needed then do the rest based on this CTE

Comment: @BagusTesa It's actually BigQuery, sorry that I wrongly put the tags

Comment: You appear to be under the impression that a CTE is a physical table, @Ching , it is *not*. As its name (Common Table **Expression**) suggests, it is an *expression*. I cannot give you alternative solutions as I don't know BigQuery, as stated.

Comment: @ThomA no worries! I first I wrote it with temp table with ROW_NUMBER Function, but the cost per query is too high, so I want to change by using CTE tables

Answer (score -2):

In Microsoft Sql-Server, you can select results into a temporary alias instead of CTE and just continue to use as long as needed.   Since TEMP tables are available for the duration of the current session, that might be all you need.  Ex:

```
SELECT 
      ID, 
      Event, 
      SN, 
      Note
   into 
      -- the # denotes a TEMP table
      #T1
   FROM 
      je
   WHERE 
          je.Event in ('1601','1602') 
      AND DATE(Time) = DATE_ADD(current_date(), INTERVAL -1 DAY);


SELECT 
      ID, 
      Event, 
      SN, 
      Note,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, 
                       case when Note like '%@%' and Event='1602' 
                            then 'Y' else 'N' end ORDER BY SN DESC) AS Sort,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, 
                       case when Note like '%@%' 
                            then 'Y' else 'N' end ORDER BY SN DESC) AS SortI1
   into
      #T2
   FROM 
      #T1

DELETE FROM A Where ID in (SELECT ID from #T2)

INSERT INTO A(
   .
   .
)
SELECT 
      .
      .
   FROM 
      G
         Left Join (SELECT DISTINCT ID, Event 
                       FROM #T2) k1 --#2
            on G.ID = k1.ID
         Left Join (SELECT ID, Event, Note like '%@%' 
                       FROM #T2 
                       where Event='1602') k2 --#3
            on G.ID = k2.ID
         Left Join (SELECT ID, Event, Note not like '%@%' 
                       FROM #T2 
                       where Event in ('1601','1602')) k3 --#4
            on G.ID = k3.ID
   WHERE 
      k1.Event in ('1601','1602');
```

FEEDBACK.

The DELETE * would fail as that is not even valid... it should just be DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE ...

As for using the TEMP tables vs CTE, I've used them regularly for years and never had a problem.

If your underlying query is invalid, then no matter how you write your queries, it would fail.  How I would resolve would be to start SSMS and open a sql query dialog.

Run the first query into #t1, then do select * from #t1 to make sure it looks as you expect.  Then (since you are still in the same session, run the query for #t2, and then select * to make sure that works.

Next, run the DELETE FROM where 1=2 and [your criteria] just to make sure the syntax is correct, then you can remove the 1=2 and clause (which will always be false and prevent any actual deletions to occur, just making sure the syntax is correct).

Then do the select from G, left join to only the first instance on its criteria.  Make sure it works.  Then add second, and finally third.  The temp #t1 and #t2 will still be there while you are working it out.

Once it is all correct, you can put into a stored procedure, but will need to be parameterized somehow as you appear to be looking for only specific events.

Comment: This will still error, as I've noted in a comment under the question.

Comment: @ThomA, see feedback comments in answer

Comment: @DRapp Thanks for the info! What if I only want to write it by using CTE? Does that mean I need to write another 3 CTE and then use each to left join?

Comment: @Ching, correct, the use of CTE is per single query following them.  So if you have one CTE with a single alias, you can use that single alias 3 times in the next single query.  But in the case as presented, they had the CTEs defined, but then had multiple individual queries... hence I suggested using temp tables which remain done once and available for duration, no matter how many queries within the same session/connection/stored procedure.